# How to convert array from (x,y)(z) dimensions into (x,y) dimensions?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am working with Bloomberg's API in VBA and I want to be able to take in the arrays that the API gives out from requesting historical data and put it into a table that has field names. However, the array that the API gives me is given in this format: (x,y)(Z) but I cannot use that for inserting into a table. I also want to be able to add another piece of data into the array while I convert from one form to another

I have tried just going through the Bloomberg array and replacing each element in a different array, but the main issues I have are not being able to know how big I need the array to be and how I am going to loop through the bloomberg API without going out of index and getting an error. I have tried using Ubound, but it does not work the way I have intended.

This is the code  I have tried using to convert my array and then insert it. It just puts in blank values and does not put in anything into the table

```
Sub mWriteToTable(vTableName As String, ByVal vArray As Variant, vCUSIPS As Variant, vFields As Variant)
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    Dim TEST As String
    Dim DataArray() As Variant

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(vTableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
    TEST = ""
    Dim xBound As Integer, yBound As Integer, ThirdBound As Integer, fieldcount As Integer, NewBoundY As Integer, Z As Integer

    Dim Boundarynum As Integer
    Boundarynum = 0
    Dim Boundarynum1 As Integer
    Boundarynum1 = 0
    fieldcount = UBound(vFields, 1) + 1
    xBound = UBound(vArray, 1)
    yBound = UBound(vArray, 2)
    NewBoundY = fieldcount * (fieldcount + 1)
    ReDim DataArray(0 To 20, 0 To (xBound + 1))
    'using a static size for the array for now. Will try and make it the same size as the bloomberg array


   'TRANSFORMING ARRAY FROM BLOOMBERG


    For x = 0 To xBound
        For y = 0 To NewBoundY
            For Boundarynum1 = 0 To yBound
        On Error Resume Next
        DataArray(Boundarynum, Boundarynum1) = vArray(x, y)(Boundarynum1)

        Next
        Boundarynum = Boundarynum + 1
       Next
            Next
    'TRANSFORMING ARRAY FROM BLOOMBERG

    'set CUSIP in array
    y = 0
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0
    For Z = 0 To 20

    If DataArray(Z, 0) = "" Then
    Debug.Print ("")
    counter = 1
    ElseIf counter = 1 And DataArray(Z, 0) <> "" Then
    y = y + 1
    DataArray(Z, 3) = vCUSIPS(y)
    counter = 0
    Else
     DataArray(Z, 3) = vCUSIPS(y)
        End If
        Next
    'set CUSIP in array

   For x = 0 To 20

        With rs
            .AddNew
            For y = 0 To yBound

'                    On Error GoTo Line1
'                     If vArray(x, y) = "NA" Then
'                    TEST = "This is a test"
'                    End If
'Line1:

                    .fields(y) = DataArray(x, y)







            Next
            .Update


        End With
    Next
    'Call fImmediateWindow(vArray)

ErrorHandler:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Dim vMsg As String
        vMsg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
        MsgBox vMsg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
'''
```

[image]

This is the way the Bloomberg Array looks when I get it. I am unsure of how to really work around this. The array from the program above just becomes blank.

Comment: Please [edit] the question end fix the formatting. All code must be preceded by four spaces, or use the `{}` button in the edit toolbar.

Comment: Have you tried using [`UBOUND()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ubound-function) and `LBOUND()` to find the size of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element of the Bloomberg array is returning 2 sets of data.  The key is to have your array have double the number of elements of the top level Bloomberg array.

```
Sub ConvertBloombergTestData()
    Dim r As Variant
    r = getBloombergTestData

    Dim Values  As Variant
    Dim n As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim Item
    ReDim Values(1 To (UBound(r) + 1) * 2, 1 To 2)
    For n = LBound(r) To UBound(r)
        j = j + 1
        Item = r(n, 0)
        Values(j, 1) = Item(0)
        Values(j, 2) = Item(1)
        Item = r(n, 1)
        j = j + 1
        Values(j, 1) = Item(0)
        Values(j, 2) = Item(1)
    Next

End Sub
```

Not knowing the the array nesting but knowing that we are returning pairs of data, we could add all the data to a collection and create our array bu iterating over the collection.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Variant, Values  As Variant
    r = getBloombergTestData
    Values = ConvertBloombergArrayTo2d(r)
End Sub

Function ConvertBloombergArrayTo2d(BloombergArray)
    Dim Map As New Collection

    FlattenArray Map, BloombergArray

    Dim Results As Variant
    ReDim Results(1 To Map.Count / 2, 1 To 2)
    Dim n As Long, j As Long

    For n = 1 To Map.Count Step 2
        j = j + 1
        Results(j, 1) = Map.Item(n)
        Results(j, 2) = Map.Item(n + 1)
    Next
    ConvertBloombergArrayTo2d = Results
End Function

Sub FlattenArray(Map As Collection, Element As Variant)
    If Right(TypeName(Element), 2) = "()" Then
        Dim Item
        For Each Item In Element
            FlattenArray Map, Item
        Next
    Else
        Map.Add Element
    End If
End Sub
```

### [image: Locals Window]